# require_once(Google/Auth/AssertionCredentials.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: google-api-php-client

I'm trying to do a very simple:

```
require_once 'vendor/google/src/Google/Client.php';
require_once 'vendor/google/src/Google/Service/Plus.php';
```

...and I get this error:

```
require_once(Google/Auth/AssertionCredentials.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Why?

I'm using the latest version available on https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client and seems that in Client.php each require_once uses a wrong path... or not?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks a lot,
Niccolò

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For your problem you need to add the base directory of the library in the php 'include_path'.

Try putting this line of code before the require_once

```
set_include_path( get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'vendor/google/src' );
```

Answer (score 1):

Above didn't work for my WordPress plugin, but I managed to solve it like this:

In `Client.php` before `require_once` block add:

```
set_include_path( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '../' );
```

Hope it helps.