# Relative Path Referencing

Tags: php, relative-path, require-once

I'm having trouble resolving paths for including Google api files. My initial file starts out like this:

```
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
set_include_path("scripts/google-api-php-client-master/src/" . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());
require_once $path . '/MyApp/scripts/google-api-php-client-master/src/Google/Client.php';
```

This seems to start off OK. But then the `Client.php` file (from Google) has its own set of `require_once` commands, and that is where things break down. For example, on line 18 of `Client.php` I have this:

```
require_once 'Google/Auth/AssertionCredentials.php';
```

which generates the following warning and error:

> Warning: require_once(Google/Auth/AssertionCredentials.php)
>   [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory in
>   D:\Hosting\11347607\html\MyApp\scripts\google-api-php-client-master\src\Google\Client.php
>   on line 18
>
> Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 
>   'Google/Auth/AssertionCredentials.php'
>   (include_path='scripts/google-api-php-client-master/src/;.;C:\php\pear')
>   in
>   D:\Hosting\11347607\html\MyApp\scripts\google-api-php-client-master\src\Google\Client.php
>   on line 18

Clearly, I am missing something with relative path referencing, but I don't know what. There are lot of similar `require_once` commands throughout the Google API tree structure, so I don't want to change their files. There must be a way that I can point to the root of this tree so that these `require_once` commands resolve correctly. Can someone please show me how to do this? Thank you.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20994928/require-oncegoogle-auth-assertioncredentials-php-failed-to-open-stream-no-su

Comment: No. I saw that post and thought it would solve the problem. All it does is change my Fatal Error a bit, but essentially the same result. The include path doesn't seem to be reaching my file, even though it looks perfect to me. Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Comment: What if you `set_include_path ("$path/MyApp/scripts/google-api-php-client-master/src/" /* ... */)`?